# Recursively reversing a sentence using void reverse() method (Java)

Tags: java

The tester class is:

```
public class SentenceWithReverseTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String[] list = new String[]{"aba", 
                                     "Madam, I'm Adam", 
                                     "nut", 
                                     "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama", 
                                     "wonderful", 
                                     "Go hang a salami, I'm a lasagna hog", 
                                     "race car", 
                                     "1", 
                                     "", 
                                     "zero", 
                                     "@!:"} ;
        for (String line : list) {
            SentenceWithReverse sentence = new SentenceWithReverse(line) ;
            sentence.reverse() ;
            System.out.println(line + "       reversed becomes........") ;
            System.out.println(sentence.toString()) ;
            System.out.println("----------------------------") ;
        }
    }
}
```

And for the reverse method I have:

```
public void reverse()
{
    String s = super.toString();
    if(s.length() > 0)
    {
        String first = s.substring(0,1);
        String remaining = s.substring(1, s.length());
        SentenceWithReverse shorter = new SentenceWithReverse(remaining);
        shorter.reverse();
        System.out.println(shorter + first);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting the result I want, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: What results *are* you getting? And how do they differ from what you wnat? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 3):

You should make `reverse()` actually return a `String`, rather than `void`, so that you can use the result of the reversal.  So change `void` to `String` in the method's declaration.  Then you'll need a couple of `return` statements inside the method - one for the base case and one for the recursive case.

In the recursive case, the `return` statement will be something like

```
return shorter.reverse() + first;
```

that is, you take the reverse of the shorter sentence, and put the first character back at the end.

In the base case, that is, where the input to the method is `""`,  you can just write

```
return "";
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out where to insert these two `return` statements, within the logic of your method.  Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

You're not assigning any member fields in your `reverse` method.  You don't show what fields you have, but I would guess you have a single String field that is returned from `toString`.  You should assign the `shorter + first` to it where you have the `System.out.println` call.